# Automate the creation of settings.php and files directory

Tags: drush, installation-profiles

I am using Drush make files and Drupal Installation profiles to streamline the creation of new Drupal websites (which are created in the sites directory of my Mac).

Everything is working fine. The Drush make file automatically downloads Drupal and all the modules I normally use on each site.

However, for each new Drupal website, I have to create a `files directory` and a `settings.php` file and then set them to writeable.

Is there any way I can automate this process, so these files are created when Drush downloads the files for the Drupal website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the `drush site-install` command. Name your installation profile with the command argument.

Answer (score 0):

I use Aegir (http://www.aegirproject.org) for managing my multisites, it not that hard to setup and provides various benefits, automated creating of settings.php and files/ directory being part of them. It also provides you web interface for managing your webistes, creating backups, restoring them, managing versions and migrations...

EDIT:
It also supports make files.